# How to pass a variable to a curl command in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am using the bash code below to store the result of a curl command in a text file.

```
cat /c/customer_files/Bain/artifacts1.txt
sample=$(curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <my_token>' '<api_>' | jq -r '.items[] | .id')
echo "$sample" >> /c/my_files/artifacts1.txt
```

This generates a text file with content below:

```
606b69cff140fe0d98e78d2a
60a40910c403d464225343b5
607f1e14d514043adcf4a0f6
60c36c380093aa519b816554
```

Now, I want to iterate through this file line by line. I am using the code below to do that.

```
while read -r line; do
#reading each line
echo "Line No. $n : $line";
n=$((n+1))
```

This is producing correct result as expected.

```
Line No. 1 : 606b69cff140fe0d98e78d2a
Line No. 2 : 60a40910c403d464225343b5
Line No. 3 : 607f1e14d514043adcf4a0f6
Line No. 4 : 60c36c380093aa519b816554
```

I want to pass variable $line to CURL command via json body below.

```
input_json="{"executable": "<some ID>", "keepTargetResources": true,"keepTargetRunProfiles": true,"advanced": {"artifactId": "$line","artifactType": "ACTION"}}"
```

However, this produces a result below:

```
,artifactType: ACTION}}d6a50bb75bbe81, keepTargetResources: true,keepTargetRunProfiles: 
true,advanced: {artifactId: 606b69cff140fe0d98e78d2a
,artifactType: ACTION}}d6a50bb75bbe81, keepTargetResources: true,keepTargetRunProfiles: 
true,advanced: {artifactId: 60a40910c403d464225343b5
,artifactType: ACTION}}d6a50bb75bbe81, keepTargetResources: true,keepTargetRunProfiles: 
true,advanced: {artifactId: 607f1e14d514043adcf4a0f6
{executable: 60ca3bf02ed6a50bb75bbe81, keepTargetResources: true,keepTargetRunProfiles: 
true,advanced: {artifactId: 60c36c380093aa519b816554,artifactType: ACTION}}
```

It creates an output in the desired format only for the last record:

```
{executable: 60ca3bf02ed6a50bb75bbe81, keepTargetResources: 
true,keepTargetRunProfiles:true,advanced: {artifactId: 
60c36c380093aa519b816554,artifactType: ACTION}}
```

For 1st 3 records, it looks like it is overwriting content at the start of the line.

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have at least one carriage return character getting into your `input_json` variable, but I'm not clear on how it's getting there. Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script to get an execution trace, and see what that indicates. One thing I see is that most of the double-quotes in that variable assignment aren't doing anything useful -- if you want double-quotes in the value, you need to escape them. I'd also recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fixing any other problems it finds.

Answer (score 0):

JSON needs to have its variables and values surrounded with `"`. Use `\` to prevent the shell to interpret the `"`.

The extra carriage return is a mystery...
Maybe an extra clean up of `line` could make it

Prefer `printf` to `echo` and use `"${line}"` for more safety.

Give this a try:

```
artifact_id="$(printf "%s" "${line}" | sed 's/^\(.*[^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]*$/\1/g')"
input_json="{\"executable\": \"<some ID>\", \"keepTargetResources\": true,\"keepTargetRunProfiles\": true,\"advanced\": {\"artifactId\": \"${artifact_id}\",\"artifactType\": \"ACTION\"}}"
```